# Is MS-CHAPv2 in windows 8.1 secure in 2020? In Windows 10?

Tags: windows, vpn

My provider still uses VPN with MS-CHAP2(no encryption). How easy can it be exploited?
I see a lot of articles but they are from 2012/2013. And some sites do not work. What is going on? Has Microsoft fixed it? Is it still not secure? How cheap such attack can be? What should I do if provider will not consider change of protocol?
What about ubuntu? does it have a better implementation of this protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fix MSCHAPv2; it's fundamentally dependent on the security of two independently-computable DES keys, which is... not quite *trivial* to brute-force at home but is doable in a day or less with a surprisingly cheap amount of hardware or even AWS time. It's not an implementation bug (which could be fixed); any implementation that conforms to the specification and is compatible with other implementations will be vulnerable. Any improvement would require changing the protocol itself, which would break compatibility; it'd be v3 rather than v2 at that point.

Microsoft has basically given up on securing MSCHAP, instructing users to instead use a secure transport (at which point you may as well send the passwords in the clear or close to it, within the tunnel, but oh well). There are also other authentication protocols that are much, much better (SRP is a cool one, but not that widely implemented in VPNs or similar at this time). Pretty much all OSes and most third-party VPN software supports at least a few of those better protocols, too.

Comment: Our provider costs ~$10/month. Will it be feasible for people to do it here?